# Classification report for binary class problem

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, binary-classification

I am building a binary CNN using single neuron in the last dense layer and "binary_crossentropy" as the loss function while compiling to predict either class1 or class2. I am having problem in creating a classification report as y_pred is a 1D array with continuous values while y_test is having binary values.

Getting following error-

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and
> continuous targets

However, if I use two neurons in the last dense layer and use "categorical_crossentropy", I was able to create confusion matrix and classification reports successfully as I was able to use `np.argmax` on y_pred and y_test

Comment: Just threshold the predicted probability, e.g. use `torch.round` (which will result in label 1 for all probabilities >= 0.5, and label 0 o/w).

Comment: Setting a threshold of $0.5$ is one option, but that makes the assumption of $0.5$ being a good threshold.

Comment: @AnvarKurmukov... used np.round and it worked!! Thanks for helping out!!

Comment: @Haider Keep in mind that doing so makes the assumption that $0.5$ is a good threshold, which need not be the case!

Comment: @Dave I am getting following results w/o using threshold. Please share if this is correct or not.



`y_pred = model.predict(test_x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
y_rounded_pred = np.round(y_pred) 
print('\n',classification_report(test_y, y_rounded_pred, target_names=class_names))`

 precision recall f1-score support
    
Class1 0.97 0.98 0.98 3742
Class2 0.92 0.92 0.92 1112
    
accuracy   0.96 4854
macro avg 0.95 0.95 0.95 4854
weighted avg 0.96 0.96 0.96 4854

[[3651   91]
 [  94 1018]]

Comment: I suspect the code is doing what you intend for it to do. However, it it totally reasonable to use thresholds like $0.4$ and $0.95$, depending on the problem. Sometimes, we even have multiple thresholds to allow for multiple actions, despite the original $y$ being binary. I recommend checking out the material linked from a [Meta post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any) that gets into dealing directly with the probability outputs and why thresholds can be problematic. Pay attention to Kolassa.

Comment: @Dave Sure, I'll check and try to implement this. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Feel free to post here or on Cross Validated as questions about that material arise. As that material is highly statistical and rather lacking in programming, Cross Validated might be the better fit, though these two Stacks have lots of overlap.